# how do use ui_component in magento2?

Tags: admin, extensions, magento2, adminhtml, grid

I have custom  **Mytable** has field(`id,name,product_id, status...`).
how do get `product name` by `product_id` in **Mytable** in file  *Mycustom\Custom\view\adminhtml\ui_component\mycustom_custom_custom_listing.xml*

Comment: i was read this. but i understand how do get product name by product_id. You can  give a concrete example resolve this problem is not? thanks @KAndy

Comment: You need create custom collection  and join product name attribute from eav and replace    `Magento\SampleGrid\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection` in example with yours

Comment: how show product name in grid @KAndy.